# Linq to sql Efficient Solution

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

Recently started with linq to sql and i am not sure what is the most efficient way to query a db and only get what i need.

```
  DataContext db = new
 DataContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnection"]);

 Table<RatesClass> CurrencyRatestbl = db.GetTable<RatesClass>();
 double Rate = 0.00;
  Rate =
      (from c in CurrencyRatestbl
      where c.From == "something"
      select Convert.ToDouble(c.Rate)).Single();
```

**I think db.GetTable get all the records from the table but i want only get one record from db, is there a way to do it.**

**Note:** the linq query will always get one record "something" is the product name, so for every product name there will be a single rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do it like this:

```
using(DataContext db = new DataContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnection"]))
{
    var rate=db.GetTable<RatesClass>()
             .Where(a=>a.From == "something")
             .Select(a=>Convert.ToDouble(a.Rate))
             .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

I also think that it is best practice to have the database context inside a using statement. So that the connection to the database is open as long as it needs. The get table do not get all the records before is it actually executed.

> Tables in a relational database are represented as Table collections
>   (which implements interfaces such as IQueryable and IEnumerable).
>   DataContext has a method called GetTable<>(); it represents a
>   potential interaction with the table of view. **The query is not
>   actually executed until iteration over the result is performed. The
>   type parameter of GetTable() identifies the table in the database**.

Reference [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c13799)

Comment: +1 for addressing the OP's actual issue, which is the incorrect assumption: "I think db.GetTable get all the records from the table"

Comment: @Arion yes that's what i wanted to know... thanks... thumbs up

Comment: Actually, there is no need for the GetTable at all. Your select should simply be rate = db.RatesClass.Where....

Comment: Yeah that's true. But the ops was about that function. That was way I post with that function.

Comment: I actually think that the gettable function is called internaly

Answer (score 0):

`Single()` will throw an Exception if your ResultSet contains 0 or more than one elements... `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` appears to be more suitable in your case.

```
DataContext db = new DataContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnection"]);
Table<RatesClass> CurrencyRatestbl = db.GetTable<RatesClass>();

double Rate = 0.00;

Rate = (from c in CurrencyRatestbl
        where c.From == "something"
        select Convert.ToDouble(c.Rate)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: the linq query will always get one record "something" is the product name, so for every product name there will be a single rate.